# How writing in debugfs controls ftrace?

Tags: linux-kernel, ftrace

Ftrace is controlled by manipulating the debug fs files. But how is it possible ? How kernel be aware of writing in this files and start its required actions?for exmple if 1 is written to tracing_on , kernel turns on tracing .
Is it something related to a special file structure or kernel subscribes to changes of debugfs or I'm missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it . according to this [link](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/master/labs/device_drivers.html)
In the kernel, a character-type device is represented by struct cdev, a structure used to register it in the system. Most driver operations use three important structures: struct file_operations, struct file and struct inode.
As mentioned above, the character device drivers receive unaltered system calls made by users over device-type files. Consequently, implementation of a character device driver means implementing the system calls specific to files: open, close, read, write, lseek, mmap, etc. These operations are described in the fields of the struct file_operations structure:

```
struct file_operations {
struct module *owner;
loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t, int);
ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
[...]
long (*unlocked_ioctl) (struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
[...]
int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);
int (*flush) (struct file *, fl_owner_t id);
int (*release) (struct inode *, struct file *);
[...]
```

so we can initialize above function pointers with our desired functions.
for example for tracing_on this is the initialization in kernel/trace/trace.c and the functions are implemented in the same file:

```
static const struct file_operations rb_simple_fops = {
.open       = tracing_open_generic_tr,
.read       = rb_simple_read,
.write      = rb_simple_write,
.release    = tracing_release_generic_tr,
.llseek     = default_llseek,
};
```

and also this is the code for creating this directory:

```
trace_create_file("tracing_on", 0644, d_tracer,
          tr, &rb_simple_fops);
```

Comment: The code in /sys/kernel/debug/tracing is implemented by the tracefs file system. You can look at the code in fs/tracefs. The tracefs file system is a pseudo file system, which means there's no actual hardware behind it (like debugfs and tmpfs). By writing 1 into tracing_on, it triggers several system calls (sys_open, sys_write, sys_close), which will follow those functions you point out, and eventually you get to rb_simple_write() which will call tracer_tracing_on() which starts enables the ring buffer to allow recording.